# Converting unsigned char to signed int

Tags: c, char, int, unsigned-integer, unsigned-char

Consider the following program

```
void main(){
  char t = 179;
  printf("%d ",t);
}
```

Output is -77.
But binary representation of 179 is

```
10110011
```

So, shouldn't output be -51, considering 1st bit is singed bit.
Binary representation of -77 is

```
11001101
```

It seems bit order is reversed. What's going on? Please somebody advice.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: To expand on the above comment, the scheme for encoding negative numbers in binary you are expecting is called [sign and magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation), which simply uses the most-significant bit as a sign bit. This is pretty much never used in practice. Negative numbers are usually implemented with the two-complement representation.

Comment: @eigenchris no it's not sign-magnitude but 2's complement. You can hardly find a 1's complement or sign-magnitude system today. Both -77 and 179's representation is 0xB3

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc perhaps I phrased my comment badly... I mean to say  sign-and-magnitude is what the OP was *expecting* based on their assumption that `10110011` is a representation of -51. Of course in truth `10110011` is -77 in the two's complement representation, which is the standard negative number representation today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You claimed that the binary representation of `-77` is `11001101`, but the reversal is yours. The binary representation of `-77` is `10110011`.

Binary `10110011` unsigned is decimal `179`.

Binary `10110011` signed is decimal `-77`.

You assigned the out-of-range value `179` to a `signed char`. It might theoretically be Undefined Behaviour, but apart from throwing an error, it would be a very poor compiler that placed anything but that 8-bit value in the `signed char`.

But when printed, it's interpreted as a negative number because b7 is set.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `char` is a signed type on your system. The valid range for a `char` would be [-128, 127]

By using

```
char t = 179;
```

the compiler uses the 2's complement of 179 (which is most likely -77) and assigns that value to `t`.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin it's not, see integer conversion rules.

Comment: @ouah It assigns a value greater than CHAR_MAX to a char. It is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ouah Quote the rule you refer to.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin c11, 6.3.1.3p3

Comment: @ouch Thanks for the pointer. Those rules say "_When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more unsigned integer than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new conversion to type. __Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it.__"_

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I don't understand how *the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more unsigned integer than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new conversion to type*. translates into 2's complement of the number being assigned. But that's a topic for another question.

Comment: @RSahu That is truncation of higher-order bits, which is well defined for unsigned types, but not for signed.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I think you didn't quote the paragraph correctly: *Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.* The important part is **the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.**

Comment: @ouah Fair enough, I often confuse _implementation-defined_ with _undefined_.

Answer (score 1):

To convert between a positive and a negative number in 2's complement you invert all the bits and then you add 1.

10110011

01001100  (invert all bits)

01001101  (add one)

That is 77 decimal

Answer (score 0):

Char could be signed or unsigned: that's up to your compiler.

If signed, it could be 2s or 1 complement.

Furthermore, it could be larger than 8 bits, although sizeof char is defined to be 1.

So it's inadvisable to rely on a specific representation.

Comment: We'll publish jointly. C++ will insist on 2s complement in the next standard: don't know about C

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that on many systems `char` is signed. Hence, when you assign 179 (which is of type `int`) to a `char` this value is outside of `char` range, hence it is unspecified behaviour.

6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers:

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more unsigned integer than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new conversion to type. **Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.**

If you change the type to `unsigned char` your program will perform correctly.

Also note that `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are 3 distinct types, unlike `int` and `signed int`. The signedness of `char` is implementation defined.

Comment: At first you said "it is undefined behavior" and now you say "it is unspecified behavior", neither is correct as C has specific definitions for these wordings. The correct thing to say is *the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised*.